# How to connect an internal mdf table in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datasource, mdf

In my ASP.Net application, I have a simple dropdown (Note: this is not an ASP element).

```
<select id="events" name="Events" style="height: 25px;"></select>
```

I was previously populating this dropdown dynamically using an API and jQuery/Javascript (Note2: This application was originally a purely javascript app but was placed in ASP.Net to get server side and other desired functionality).

```
let dropdown = $('#events');


//Function to call Asp.Net Web Service and retrieve events list by state
var EventsData = esriRequest({
    url: "RII_Service.asmx/GetListOfEventsByState",
    content: {       
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    handleAs: "json"
});
EventsData.then(
function (response) {
    events_json = response.ListEvents;
    console.log(events_json);

    dropdown.empty();
    dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose Event Name</option>');
    dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    //Initialize state dropdown on load
    if ((document.getElementById("state").value !== null) && (document.getElementById("state").value !== undefined) && (document.getElementById("state").value !== "undefined")) {
        var state_pre = document.getElementById("state");
        state_name = state_pre.options[state_pre.selectedIndex].value;
        filtered_events = events_json.filter(event => (event.State.trim() === state_name));
        options = filtered_events.map(event => event.FullEventName);
        console.log(options);
        $.each(options, function (i, el) {
            if ($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
        });
        $.each(uniqueNames, function (i, p) {
            $('#events').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
        });
    }
}, function (error) {
    console.log("Error: ", error.message);
});
```

I have created a simple `.mdf` SQL database inside my application to replace calling this API and using an ASP.Net WebService:

[image]

It has a table called `'Events'` that I want to use to populate my dropdown:
[image]

Although I am not connecting to an outside datasource like `SQLServer` or an API, I am still confused as to how to bring in my table and populate the dropdown using my internal `.mdf` table. Any suggestions on how to do this? Do I still need the `WebService` file or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) first of all You have to deattach database from SQL server
a) open SQL server
b) connect your server
c) open node of database and right-click on your database and choose task menu and then choose deattach then database will deattached

2) In the second step in the visual studio right-click on app_data folder and click on add existing item and then select database which you want to add in app_data folder it will be in In my case ( C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\accountdb.mdf) and now this database will add in app_data folder

3) Now change your connection string in the config file
Collapse | Copy Code

```
<connectionstrings>
        <add connectionstring="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Accountdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True  " name="ConnectionASPX" providername="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionstrings>
```

Comment: OK, I got the connection string. I even created a stored procedure in the mdf. So the local mdf needs to be 'X'd' out (detached)? Do I need to create a data entity model or something with a class that I can call my stored procedure with?

Comment: yes you can call a stored procedure from code behind and get data and pass to the web service response